# How to allocate more memory to C code

Tags: c, arrays, memory, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    long int length = atol(*++argv);

    long int a[length];

    // write and read it, so it doesn't get optimized out:
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        a[i] = i;    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        if (a[i] != i)
            return 1;
}
```

The program above runs in most cases, however when I try to initialise the array `a` with a large number (such as `1967791`) I get a segmentation fault. Is there a way I can allocate more memory to the program so this doesn't happen?

I am running this program on a Virtual Machine using Linux.

Comment: Use `malloc` instead of putting the array on the stack. You can usually get a lot more memory out of `malloc` than you can out of the stack.

Comment: For me `argv[1]` is very much easier to read than `*++argv`. Also changing `argv` may not be desireable.

Answer (score -1):

You need to allocate memory on the heap, rather than on the stack:

```
  long int *a = malloc(array_length * sizeof *a);
```

Don't forget to `free()` it when it's no longer needed.

Comment: In C, do not cast the return value of `malloc`, it can hide bugs.